# Passing in objects to __init__ or passing a common param to and constructing objects inside __init__?

Tags: python

I have a class `Foo` that creates instances of other classes `A`, `B`, and `C` in its constructor. `A`, `B`, and `C` share the same constructor parameter and are used in other parts of the codebase, not just in `Foo`. `A`, `B`, and `C` access an outside resource configured by the passed parameter. In unit tests, `A`, `B`, and `C` are mocked out with `unittest.mock.patch`.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, param):
        self.a = A(param)
        self.b = B(param)
        self.c = C(param)

foo = Foo('param')
```

Would the following be an improvement or just unnecessary code? Is passing in `unittest.mock.Mock` objects in tests preferred over using `unittest.mock.patch`? In practice, `A`, `B`, and `C` should always share the same parameter.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    @classmethod
    def from_param(cls, param):
        return cls(A(param), B(param), C(param))

foo = Foo.from_param('param')
```

Comment: Is the “should always share the same parameter” an invariant or just the current use-case?

Comment: Current use-case, but unlikely to change. A, B, and C are all wrappers around different groups of endpoints around a web service and share the same base URL.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little hard to reason about in isolation but I generally like the second approach better. It gives you the flexibility to pass any three objects (including your mocks). If it is not a class invariant that they all be constructed with the same parameters, this seems to be a good thing. The `classmethod` you provide for the case that you want `A`, `B`, `C` constructed with the same parameters makes it still convenient to use in the common case. And you can add more convenience factory functions later shall there be a need.

Of course, you shouldn't over-abstract either but the fact that you think about mocking hints me that this is not the case here.